# Can't pass token in the request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, jwt

I have a  nodeJs authentication system that register a user on /auth/register and creates a token and return it in the response on /auth/login. Except these two routes every other one go through an authMiddleware that checks if the headers of the request include an Authorisation header with the token. If it is it next() if not it throws an error 401. (there are also the two routes that render the views ).

here is my controller :

```
const AuthenticationError = require("../errors/authError");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/user");

module.exports = {
  renderRegisterPage: (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("register");
  },

  register: async ({ body: { username, password, email } }, res, next) => {
    try {
      const newUser = new User({ username, password, email });
      await newUser.save();
      res.status(200).end();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },

  renderLoginPage: (req, res, next) => {
    res.render("login");
  },

  login: async (req, res, next) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ username });
      if (!user)
        throw new AuthenticationError("User not found : invalid username", 404);

      const passwordMatch = await user.comparePassword(password);
      if (!passwordMatch)
        throw new AuthenticationError("Incorrect password", 401);

      const token = jwt.sign({ userId: user.id }, process.env.SECRET_KEY, {
        expiresIn: "1h",
      });
      res.status(200).json({ token });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  },
};
```

Here is the authMiddleware :

```
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const User = require("../models/user");
const AuthenticationError = require("../errors/authError");

module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization?.split(" ")[1];
  try {
    console.log(token);
    if (!token) throw new AuthenticationError("Authentication required", 401);
    const decodedToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
    const user = await User.findById(decodedToken.userId);
    if (!user) throw new AuthenticationError("User not found", 404);
    req.user = user;
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
};
```

In my login view on submit I make a request on /auth/login the result is good. I got my token but on the redirect the request does not have the token in the headers so it goes to an Error. I did not find any way to pass the token to the request. And I will need do the same for the rest of my app. Is it that it is not the right way to use it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/auth.css" />
    <title>Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <form id="loginForm">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="username" required />

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" id="password" name="password" required />

      <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>

    <script>
      document
        .getElementById("loginForm")
        .addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var formData = {
            username: document.getElementById("username").value,
            password: document.getElementById("password").value,
          };

          fetch("http://localhost:6543/auth/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData),
          })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(({ token }) => {
              localStorage.setItem("token", token);
              window.location.href = "/home";
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log("Error:", error);
            });
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the link of the repo if you want to have a look : https://github.com/MaximeArn/ecommerce.git

Comment: you say you `can't pass token in request` - yet you haven't shown the code that would attempt to do so

Comment: oh, I see - you've stored the token in `localStorage` - the traditional way to do this is to use `cookies`

Comment: @JaromandaX the problem is that when I change the href in the then block of my request the browser will make a request to the server but without passing the token in the headers. Is there a way to add it. 
I tried to do the request by myself in the then block I made a GET request and I passed the token in the headers but the browser location does not change.

Comment: that's what cookies are for

Comment: @JaromandaX I have never used cookies. If I store the token in the cookies it will make it available in all the next requests ?

Comment: yes, that's how cookies work. actually, with such tokens it's more common for the server to set the cookie in the login response (and making it a http only cookie, but that's not important right now) - therefore the front end code need not worry about it at all

Comment: @JaromandaX ok thanks a lot I will look at this tomorrow.